# Parse lines written to standard out in "real time"

Tags: powershell, script, redirection, stdout

First, I having only been learning Powershell for about a week primarily adapting Linux scripts to run on my (more powerful) Windows machine. So, please be kind with the lingo.

I am trying to write a script that parses a stream of string data written to stdout by another command as it is being written. The amount of data being written is large and lengthy and it would be nice to process it as it is written instead of writing it to a text file and then subsequently processing that.

The output is ASCII strings with a newline delimiter (or being Windows, perhaps a carriage return as well). Here is effectively want I want to do:

```
foreach ($i in (ffprobe -i "$sourceFile" -show_frames))
{

    if ("$i".Substring(0,1) -eq "[" -and "$i".Substring(1,1) -ne "/")
    {
        echo "$i".Substring(0,1)
        echo "$i".Substring(1,1)
        echo "$i"
        <do other stuff>
    }
}
```

The `ffprobe -i "$sourceFile" -show_frames` command outputs text such as:

```
[FRAME]
DATA1
DATA1
[/FRAME]
```

Basically I want to treat the data being written to stdout as a 'while loop' until there is no more content being written. I only need to parse one line of data at a time. All said and done, I would expect the number of lines being output to range in the ballpark of 5 - 10 million lines.

FYI, my machine should be able to handle the amount of data. I have dual Xeon E5 v3 with 12 cores (24 w/ hyperthreading) and 128GB RAM. As I process the data, approximately every 10-15 lines of output will be processed and written to a text file - though I may create a buffer variable to write the processed output to and flush it to a file every few thousand lines of output.

Thanks in advance for some guidance.

Comment: I guess you are aware of [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) and Cygwin etc.

Comment: I am aware but do not see a readily workable solution. The problem is that the ffprobe output will be part of a larger script using ffmpeg to encode content. While I realize WSL & cygwin can both handle this as well, they cannot not utilize hardware acceleration - from what I have researched. Had either been able to utilize my GPU, I would have used existing scripts. Though, as I write, I realize I haven't tried entering an WSL session within a Powershell script to execute ffprobe content and return desired data for the rest of the script. I will do some research and see if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following resolved my problem. I do not know if it is the most efficient but it works for me. If you have a more efficient way, I welcome it.

```
wsl ffprobe -i "$sourceFile" -show_frames 2>1 | ForEach-Object ($_) {
    if ("$_".Substring(0,1) -eq "[" -and "$_".Substring(1,1) -ne "/")
        {
            echo $i
            echo "$_".Substring(0,1)
            echo "$_".Substring(1,1)
            echo "$_"

        }
    }
```

*********** UPDATE 2020-04-12 ***********

It turns out that I did not need to use WSL - it was just the first solution I discovered. The above solution will work as written without or without using `wsl` (plus you avoid possible naming problems associated with passing Windows files to WSL). So, there is no need for WSL in this case. Initially when I was testing approaches in Powershell, I think it failed due to a syntax error. Specifically, the following setup failed:

```
ffprobe -i "$sourceFile" -show_frames 2>1 | ForEach-Object ($_) 
{ # Open Brace in this line instead of previous line
    if ("$_".Substring(0,1) -eq "[" -and "$_".Substring(1,1) -ne "/")
        {
            echo $i
            echo "$_".Substring(0,1)
            echo "$_".Substring(1,1)
            echo "$_"
        }
}
```

Notice that the open brace `{` for the `ForEach-Object` is not on the same line as the `ForEach-Object` command but rather on the next line. For reasons I do not know, the Powershell script would fail. However, when set up like the solution above without the `wsl` such that the `ForEach-Object` opening brace `{` is on the same line, the piped input into the loop works without problems. So, just to be thorough, here is how the solution without `wsl` looks:

```
ffprobe -i "$sourceFile" -show_frames 2>1 | ForEach-Object ($_) {
    if ("$_".Substring(0,1) -eq "[" -and "$_".Substring(1,1) -ne "/")
        {
            echo $i
            echo "$_".Substring(0,1)
            echo "$_".Substring(1,1)
            echo "$_"

        }
    }
```